# Github action cache image used multi-stage build

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a multi-stage build that uses a docker image which contains all the `node_modules` needed for a build and other dependencies. I used that in a multi-stage docker build to build a production dist for a project. In the 2nd stage I use a much smaller docker to store the dist files so it's easier to distribute.

Dockerfile for the build:

```
FROM ghcr.io/dancing-star/packages-image-full:latest AS builder

# Make the dir
WORKDIR /var/dancing-star

COPY . .

# Set the cache location
RUN npm config set cache /tmp/node-cache --global \
    && npm run prod \
    && rm -rf src \
    && ls -l

# Dist stage
FROM alpine
WORKDIR /var/dancing-star
COPY --from=builder ["/var/dancing-star/dist", "/var/dancing-star/assets", "/var/dancing-star/config", "/var/dancing-star/scripts", "/var/dancing-star/*.json", "/var/dancing-star/*.md", "/var/dancing-star/*.js", "/var/dancing-star/"]
RUN ls -l


#CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "start", "app.pm2.json", "--env", "production" ]
```

The `ghcr.io/dancing-star/packages-image-full` contains the `node_modules` and works fine. I used a github action to cache `ghcr.io/dancing-star/packages-image-full` but it doesn't seem to be caching it very well since it's constantly pulling it again.

`.github/workflows/docky.yaml`

```
name: Build Docker

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
    tags:
      - v*

env:
  IMAGE_NAME: project-docker
  BUILD_IMAGE_NAME: ghcr.io/naologic/dancing-star/packages-image-full
  BUILD_IMAGE_PATH: ghcr.io/naologic/dancing-star/packages-image-full:latest

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      packages: write
      contents: read
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2
      - name: Login to GitHub Container Registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_DEPLOY_GITHUB }}
      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          context: .
          file: Dockerfile
          push: true
          tags: ${{ env.BUILD_IMAGE_PATH }}
          cache-from: type=registry,ref=${{ env.BUILD_IMAGE_NAME }}:buildcache
          cache-to: type=registry,ref=${{ env.BUILD_IMAGE_NAME }}:buildcache,mode=max
```

IMPORTANT: `ghcr.io/dancing-star/packages-image-full` is shared between many builds so ideally it would be a shared cache.

How should I use actions to cache `ghcr.io/dancing-star/packages-image-full` for the build?

My solution doesn't seem to be working very well.

- I tried the current action, cache still pulls for 2 minutes before starting
- I tried without cache, build time is about the same

Comment: Not sure if helpful, but since you're using a multi-stage Dockerfile, I'd guess you'd be better off setting a label for every stage (basically adding `as dist` or something to that affect to `FROM alpine` where you want your "dist stage"), and then passing the target stage label (`dist` if following the example) to `docker/build-push-action` (via its `target` property, inside `with` in the workflow YAML). If this does achieve what you expect, I'll convert this into a full-fledged answer, but either way, I have no idea which target gets pushed if you don't specify any with a multi-stage build.

Comment: Also, AFAIK, `COPY` Dockerfile directives are rather tricky about caching (even with local builds, talking from previous experience)... Sometimes they are used as-is from cache and you have to force `--no-cache` (mainly when using compose) even when files have changed, and sometimes they're always re-built, thus nullifying the caches for any steps after that...